# Xquery problem in counting

Tags: xquery

[image]

Using XQuery:

List the id, name, publisher and platforms for each game that is supported by more than one
platform. Platforms should be enclosed in one XML tag delimited by a comma.

I am getting problem in thinking that how do i count the patforms. The platforms that I need to count is given like in the above figure. Playstation3,XBox are the patlforms for one game. Outside the box, under it, that format of data is given.Please help me in it.

Comment: @user507087: Please, don't change your questions. That makes them no meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XQuery:

```
element result {
   for $game in /games/game[tokenize(Platform,',')[2]]
   return element game {
             $game/(ID|Name|Publisher|Platform)
          }
}
```

With this input:

```
<games>
    <game>
        <ID>B003JVKHEQ</ID>
        <Name>Duty</Name>
        <Publisher>AC</Publisher>
        <ESRB>M</ESRB>
        <Motion>False</Motion>
        <Platform>Playstation3,XBox</Platform>
    </game>
</games>
```

Output:

```
<result>
    <game>
        <ID>B003JVKHEQ</ID>
        <Name>Duty</Name>
        <Publisher>AC</Publisher>
        <Platform>Playstation3,XBox</Platform>
    </game>
</result>
```

**Edit**: With literal result elements

```
 <result>{
   for $game in /games/game[tokenize(Platform,',')[2]]
   return  <game>{
              $game/(ID|Name|Publisher|Platform)
          }</game>
}</result>
```

Comment: tokenize(Platform,',')[2]]  - why you have used 2 here??And You have also used the keyword element in the query?is it a function.I read the documentation, but i dont find it there

Comment: @user507087: About `element`, see [Computed Element Constructors](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-computedElements).

Comment: @user507087: About `tokenize(Platform,',')[2]`: Why I would use `count(tokenize(Platform,',')) ge 2` (counting all and test if greater or equal than 2) when I can test if there is a second item?

Comment: Can we do it without using element??

Comment: @user507087: Yes. With literal result elements. I will update the answer.

Comment: tokenize is not working on my platform. It is throwing me an error.Is there any other way?

Comment: @user507087: What's your XQuery processor?

Answer (score 0):

If your XQuery engine supports XPath 2.0 you can use the `tokenize` function to count items of a comma separated list:

```
count(tokenize("Playstation3,XBox",","))
```

Does that help? If not could you please provide a complete example with XML input and expected result. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please send me your email id on my id: shib.shilpa@gmail.com. I can sendyou my xml file over there.Plz help me.

Comment: I cant put the names of platforms here like playstation3, xbox. I have to make it independent. Just count the platforms.